# TimePickerDialog and time zone

Tags: java, android, timepicker

I create a `TimePickerDialog` wtih the following line of code : `new TimePickerDialog(context,new Listener(),0,1,true);`
.

My problem is that the `TimePicker`, as a result, displays "12:01" instead of "00:01". I can add this problem arises when I use English locale.

Any idea?

Comment: I see nothing time zone related in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, the problem only arises when the emulator is used. With a real phone, the "TimePickerDialog" correctly displays "00:01".

Answer (score 0):

you should try 24 hour time format to have required out put. you can use `setIs24HourView(true)` with [TimePicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html#setIs24HourView%28java.lang.Boolean%29).

Comment: That's also the last field in the `TimePickerDialog` constructor, which is set to `true` in the OP.

Comment: Geobits is right : the last parameter already asks the TimePicker to use 24 hours format.

Comment: In fact, the problem only arises when the emulator is used. With a real phone, the "TimePickerDialog" correctly displays "00:01".